# row number partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Sorry for the potentially misleading title wasn't sure what to call it.

I need to workout how to find Incidents where only one Person has been mobilised to it.  I figured I'd be able to achieve this by using Row_Number partition and then filtering on 1

```
 RowNumber    Incident MobilisedDateTime     Name
    1          abc     2019-02-08            Fred
    2          abc     2019-02-08            Roger
    3          abc     2019-02-08            Brian
    4          abc     2019-02-08            John
    1          def     2019-02-08            Joe
    1          ghi     2019-02-07            Robert
    1          jkl     2019-02-06            Jimmy
    2          jkl     2019-02-06            John
```

This is what happens when filtering on row number 1. This is not what I'm after because Incident 'abc' and 'jkl' had more than one person mobilised to it.

```
    RowNumber Incident MobilisedDateTime     Name
    1          abc     2019-02-08            Fred
    1          def     2019-02-08            Joe
    1          ghi     2019-02-07            Robert
    1          jkl     2019-02-06            Jimmy
```

The result I would like to see is this

```
    RowNumber Incident MobilisedDateTime     Name
     1          def     2019-02-08           Joe
     1          ghi     2019-02-07           Robert
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method is probably `not exists`.  Window functions are not needed:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.incident = t.incident and
                        t2.name <> t.name
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(incident, name)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, this will return your result

```
select RowNumber,Incident,MobilisedDateTime,max(Name) as name,count(distinct name) as cnt from table_name group by RowNumber,Incident,MobilisedDateTime  having(count(distinct name) = 1)
```